# How to only let the author of comments edit, update & destroy them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, userid

I'm trying to prevent all users being able to edit, update and destroy comments made to posts in my forum. I managed to prevent all users editing the posts, but i can't work out what i need to do to prevent all users editing the comments.

I solved the post issue with this before_action in the post controller:

```
before_action :post_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

This is my show.html.haml:

```
#post_content

%h1= @post.title
%p= @post.content

#comments
    %h2
        = @post.comments.count
        Comments
    = render @post.comments

    - if user_signed_in?

        %h3 Reply to thread
        = render'comments/form'

        %br/
        %hr/
        %br

        - if @post.user_id == current_user.id
            = link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "button"
            = link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to do this?"}, class: "button"
```

I added a before_action for comments in the post_controller and tried this in the _comment.html.haml:

```
.comment.clearfix
.content
    %p.comment_content= comment.comment
    %p.comment_author= comment.user.email

%br/
%br/
%br/
%br/

- if @comment.user_id == current_user.id

    = link_to "Edit", edit_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), class: "button"

    = link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "button"
```

However i receive the following error:

```
undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
```

I think this is a simple solution but i'm not that experienced with ruby on rails just yet.

Comment: From your code, it looks like the variable should be `comment`, not `@comment`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the error. I knew it was something simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In _comment.html.haml, you are using `@comment`, which probably is not declared anywhere. Changing it to `comment` should fix the issue

```
- if comment.user_id == current_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this nil:NilClass error because you get instance variable @comment nil, so that's why you didn't get user_id from @comment and getting this error.

So change the **@comment** variable to **comment** and you will get the user_id.

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed it :)